# Calling the rest video intelligence API in JAVA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I've been trying to call the rest API of video intelligence through a java program to annotate a local file. Here is my code:

```
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(data);

        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1beta2/videos:annotate");
        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("X-Goog-Api-Key",MyKey);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put("LABEL_DETECTION");
        json.put("inputContent", encodedBytes);
        json.put("features", jsonArray);

        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I'm getting this error: 
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"input_content\": Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.

Could anyone help me with this error please? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not really helpful. Problem here is that "inputContent" should be `String` instead of `byte[]`. This worked for me:

```
String str = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
requestJson.put("inputContent", str);
```

Comment: @MounaBenChamekh glad to help, please consider accepting the answer